# Отображение текста в MenuItem Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, menuitem

Подскажите, пожалуйста в Xamarin.Forms возможно выполнить перенос слов в MenuItem, стандартно если длина строки превышает ширину Item то текст просто обрезается. Обшарил все свойства но не могу разобраться как это сделать. Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть [такая штука](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41403161/12888024) с кнопкой, может и с меню прокатит.